# adding line in a file to a list results in None

Tags: python, json

I need to group lines in a file having same id and  create list of such lines. I tried following code which fails

```
def combiner(file):
    exts = dict()
    for each_line in open(file):
        each_line = each_line.rstrip()
        id = get_id_from_aggExtract(json.loads(each_line))
        if id in exts.keys():
            print id
            lists = exts.get(id).append(each_line)
            print type(lists)
        else:
            lists = list()
            lists.append(each_line)
            print id
        exts[id] = lists
    print exts
    return list(exts.values())
```

After parsing some lines the following error is seen

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
lists = exts.get(id).append(each_line)
```

`append` returns `None`... so `lists` will be None... You'll have to retrieve the original list via `exts.get(id)` again or do;

```
lists = exts.get(id)
lists.append(each_line)
```

You'd be better of using a `defaultdict`, eg:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

def combiner(filename):
    exts = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            json_line = json.loads(line)
            key = get_id_from_aggExtract(json_line)
            exts[key].append(line)
    return exts
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. that helps me. I tried below can you let me know why it didn't worked for me: lists = exts.get(id)
lists = lists.append(each_line)

Comment: @user2595808 Remove the `lists = ` from the line with `append`, which is exactly what Jon said in his answer - just in a few more words.